# Negative drain current in FET

Tags: simulation, fet, ads

I am new to electronics simulation.
I am currently simulating a simple FET where I sweep both the gate and drain voltages.

[image: Circuit schematic]

When I plot the drain currents for low values of the drain voltage I obtain a negative current value.
I am actually not understanding the reason behind this.
I am aware that a small negative current in possible if the voltage between drain and source becomes negative, but here Vds is always >=0.
If you can tell me where´s the mistake, I would really appreciate.

Many thanks

[image: Drain current plot]

Comment: Are you simulating a MOSFET or a JFET? I suspect its an N-type JFET. A JFET has **diodes** between gate and drain/source. Observe the gate current, is there current flowing into the gate when \$V_{DS}\$ = 0 V ? A N-type JFET is typically operated with a **negative** \$V_{GS}\$ (which you do not have). I suggest that you change the "FET" for an N-channel MOSFET.

Comment: What sweep rate speed are you using?

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie Thanks for your reply. Actually I wasn´t aware if it was a MOSFET or a JFET. As suggested by you, I´ve checked the gate current and found out that this is different from 0. So, with a JFET, it´s possible to obtain a negative drain current also keeping the drain voltage at 0?